# In Android Studio how do you find which dependency to add?

Tags: android, android-studio

This is a basic question I can't find an answer to. For example I want to use a class called `CompositeCollection` but I can't find what to add under Dependencies in app gradle in order to use it. It's probably org.apache.commons.something. Unlike other dependencies which get added automatically by Android Studio (like androidx.anything) ones like this don't so I have to add them manually.

Going to `File > Project Structure > Dependencies > +` doesn't help since nothing shows up in that search unless you already know the name of the dependency beforehand. Googling the `CompositeCollection` class didn't tell me the dependency either.

Comment: When I search for `CompositeCollection java` in search engines, I see that it appears to be part of Apache Commons Collections.

Comment: So how do I know exactly what to add?

Comment: Ideally, you look in the documentation for the library to see what to add. Unfortunately, Apache libraries sometimes make this challenging. Searching search engines on `apache commons collections maven` will turn up the Maven dependency details shown in the answer.

Comment: Those are very specific keywords

Comment: Well, `apache commons collection` is the name of the library, which you get from the first search engine query. `maven` is the name of the artifact repository type typically used for Android dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this for maven :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
  <version>4.4</version>
</dependency>
```

or this for gradle:

```
implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.4'
```

Comment: Ok but how did you find this? And is there a way to have Android Studio automatically add this dependency like it does with other ones?

Comment: well believe it or not i just did a search for 2 minutes. I don't know if you can have it done automatically or not but apache has really good documentation so it shouldn't be hard given you search for the right terms. also, please accept the answer as correct if it worked for you.